# connecting scales(measure weight) to external device(pc or iphone)

Tags: php, ios, api, serial-port

I want to make a project for a client where client can easily weigh a product and get the product weight displayed on his PC or iPhone before submitting the data to a web server, I know some scales have APIs but could they be integrated into the web browser? or should I do a custom desktop or mobile application to handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the scales are network capable, then you can write an application using [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite).

If the scales have serial port only, you'll either need a PC connected to it or some embedded device acting like a server. See this [device](http://www.visionsystems.de/vscom-serial-device-server.html) for example, if you want an industrial grade device with rugged case and variable input voltage or you can also take [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) or [BeagleBone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBone#BeagleBone). The server can either provide data over some IP port with defined API or you can implement a web-server there, so that you'll only need a browser on your smartphone (iOS, Android etc.)